How to setup partitionID and SigningRegion in AWS smithy-go endpoint?
I have been used a custom endpoint resolver as follows
func loadAWSConfig() aws.Config {
    endpoint := os.Getenv("MOCK_AWS_ENDPOINT")
    if endpoint != "" {
        fmt.Println("Running AWS with custom endpoint resolver: ", endpoint)
        cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background(), config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions(aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc(func(service, region string, options ...any) (aws.Endpoint, error) {
            return aws.Endpoint{
                PartitionID:   "aws",
                URL:           endpoint,
                SigningRegion: region,
            }, nil
        })))
        if err != nil {
            panic("unable to load SDK config, " + err.Error())
        }
        return cfg
    }

    cfg, err := config.LoadDefaultConfig(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        panic("unable to load SDK config, " + err.Error())
    }
    return cfg
}

The problem is, AWS has deprecated config.WithEndpointResolverWithOptions, aws.EndpointResolverWithOptionsFunc and aws.Endpoint. They encourage us to use EndPointResolverV2 to replace deprecated.
I've tried with the following
import transport "github.com/aws/smithy-go/endpoints"

type resolverS3 struct {
}

func (r resolverS3) ResolveEndpoint(ctx context.Context, params s3.EndpointParameters) (transport.Endpoint, error) {
    if endpoint := os.Getenv("MOCK_AWS_ENDPOINT"); endpoint != "" {
        u, err := url.Parse(endpoint)
        if err != nil {
            return transport.Endpoint{}, err
        }
        return transport.Endpoint{URI: *u}, nil
    }
    // delegate back to the default v2 resolver otherwise
    return s3.NewDefaultEndpointResolverV2().ResolveEndpoint(ctx, params)
}

func GetS3Instance() *s3.Client {
    return s3.NewFromConfig(loadAWSConfig(), s3.WithEndpointResolverV2(resolverS3{}))
}

But this reports no specified bucket fount error. I noticed that I'm not setting the PartitionID and SigningRegion in custom resolver, How can I set it with transport.Endpoint?

I have a hunch that AWS is trying hard to prohibit using competitors (S3-compatible APIs) with this deprecation. They have SigningRegion defined as a parameter, which they say "If you are implementing your own EndpointResolverV2, you should never need to construct your own instance of EndpointParameters."
